# Choose file to upload dialog. Merge VBS and VBA process

Tags: vba, internet-explorer, vbscript, ie-automation

Hi i have two procedures:

1. Click button to open dialog box in IE
2. To enter data to that dialog box
   Both of them work seperatly

The problem is that VBA wont proceed to 2nd procedure if dialog box is open.
I think  work around would be to launch vbs script (which holds all interaction with dialog box) prior to vba and it would solve automation problem.

I have both of them in VBA. So is this feasable? If yes I would need help to do VBS script.
Also how to pass path variable from VBA to VBS.

1st part:

```
Sub matchwww()
marker = 0
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
my_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location
my_title = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Title

If my_title Like "Invoice Submission" & "*" Then 'compare to find if the desired web page is already open
    Set IE = objShell.Windows(x)
    marker = 1
    Exit For
Else
End If
Next
'Dim html As HTMLDocument
If marker = 0 Then
MsgBox ("A matching webpage was NOT found")
Else
Set html = IE.Document

'Call UploadfileAutomation
msgmarker = 0


For Each msg_not In html.getElementsByClassName("ripsStdTxtBox")
msg_not.Click
Next msg_not


End If ' this End If of matchwww main statement
End Sub
```

2nd part:

```
Sub UploadfileAutomation()

SaveAsWindow = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Choose file to Upload")
If SaveAsWindow = 0 Then
MsgBox "Couldn't find the SaveAsWindow"

End If
TextComboBox = FindWindowEx(SaveAsWindow, 0&, "ComboBoxEx32", vbNullString)
If SaveAsWindow = 0 Then
MsgBox "Couldn't find the SaveAsWindow"

End If
ComboBox = FindWindowEx(TextComboBox, 0&, "ComboBox", vbNullString)
If ComboBox = 0 Then
MsgBox "Couldn't find the ComboBox"

End If
EditComboBox = FindWindowEx(ComboBox, 0&, "Edit", vbNullString)
If EditComboBox = 0 Then
MsgBox "Couldn't find the EditComboBox"

End If
''and wait/sleep
Call SendMessageByString(EditComboBox, WM_SETTEXT, 0, "Path variable") 
DoEvents
SaveButton = FindWindowEx(SaveAsWindow, 0&, "Button", "&Open")
Call EnableWindow(SaveButton, True)
Call SendMessage(SaveButton, BM_CLICK, 0&, ByVal 0&)
End Sub
```

test vbs script just to close BOX

```
Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.shell")

Do
ret = wshShell.appActivate("Choose file to upload")
Loop until ret = True

Wscript.sleep 5
ret = wshShell.appActivate("Choose file to upload")
if ret= true then
ret = wshShell.appActivate("Choose file to upload")
Wscript.sleep 10
wshShell.sendkeys "%{F4}"
End if
```

Functions for other who would use this approach

```
 Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
 Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByRef lParam As Any) As Long
 Public Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SendMessageByString Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Any) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function SetActiveWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Public Declare PtrSafe Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nCmdSHow As Long) As Long
 Public Declare PtrSafe Function BringWindowToTop Lib "user32" (ByVal lngHWnd As Long) As Long
 Public Declare PtrSafe Function EnableWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal fEnable As Long) As Long
 Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
 Public Declare PtrSafe Function GetFocus Lib "user32.dll" () As Long

 Public Const WM_CLOSE As Long = &H10
 Public Const SW_SHOW As Integer = 5
 Public Const WM_SETTEXT As Long = &HC
 Public Const BM_CLICK As Long = &HF5&
```

Comment: So after reading  a lot it appears, that it's impossible to use user32.dll in VBS script without workarounds.  Maybe its possible to write it in VB6.

Comment: Questions are marked as solved by accepting an answer. If you need to, you can add your solution as an answer to your own question, and then accept your own answer. Please don't vandalize any questions by changing the title or contents to include the word "solved".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if anybody is interested in solution here it's(hope it helps everybody):

I compiled .exe with VB6 which interacts with Upload File dialog:

```
 Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
 Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByRef lParam As Any) As Long
 Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
 Private Declare Function SendMessageByString Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Any) As Long
 Private Declare Function SetActiveWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
 Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nCmdSHow As Long) As Long
 Private Declare Function BringWindowToTop Lib "user32" (ByVal lngHWnd As Long) As Long
 Private Declare Function EnableWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal fEnable As Long) As Long
 Private Declare Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
 Private Declare Function GetFocus Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
 Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
 Private Const WM_CLOSE As Long = &H10
 Private Const SW_SHOW As Integer = 5
 Private Const WM_SETTEXT As Long = &HC
 Private Const BM_CLICK As Long = &HF5&

Public Sub Main() 'is nessesary to execute on launch
Dim strCommandLine As String 'path passed from VBA
strCommandLine = Command 'path passed from VBA
Sleep 25000 'wait to execute, can be smarter way to check if dialog is already open

SaveAsWindow = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Choose file to Upload")
If SaveAsWindow = 0 Then
MsgBox "Couldn't find the SaveAsWindow" 'msg boxes are just for troubleshooting to see if right elements are found or not

End If
TextComboBox = FindWindowEx(SaveAsWindow, 0&, "ComboBoxEx32", vbNullString)
If SaveAsWindow = 0 Then
MsgBox "Couldn't find the SaveAsWindow"

End If
ComboBox = FindWindowEx(TextComboBox, 0&, "ComboBox", vbNullString)
If ComboBox = 0 Then
MsgBox "Couldn't find the ComboBox"

End If
EditComboBox = FindWindowEx(ComboBox, 0&, "Edit", vbNullString)
If EditComboBox = 0 Then
MsgBox "Couldn't find the EditComboBox"

 End If
 ''and wait/sleep
  Call SendMessageByString(EditComboBox, WM_SETTEXT, 0, strCommandLine) 'here goes variable from VBA "strCommandLine"
  DoEvents
  SaveButton = FindWindowEx(SaveAsWindow, 0&, "Button", "&Open")
  Call EnableWindow(SaveButton, True)
  Call SendMessage(SaveButton, BM_CLICK, 0&, ByVal 0&)
  End Sub
```

VBA Part:

```
Sub matchwww()
marker = 0
Dim strProgramName As String
Dim strArgument As String

strProgramName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\UploadInvoice.exe"
strArgument = "I:\testetetstest.xls"

Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
IE_count = objShell.Windows.Count
For x = 0 To (IE_count - 1)
On Error Resume Next    ' sometimes more web pages are counted than are open
my_url = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Location
my_title = objShell.Windows(x).Document.Title

If my_title Like "Invoice Submission" & "*" Then 'compare to find if the desired web page is already open
    Set IE = objShell.Windows(x)
    marker = 1
    Exit For
 Else
 End If
 Next
'Dim html As HTMLDocument
If marker = 0 Then
MsgBox ("A matching webpage was NOT found")
Else
Set html = IE.Document


msgmarker = 0

Call Shell("""" & strProgramName & """ """ & strArgument & """", vbNormalFocus) 'we need to call prior dialog is open
For Each msg_not In html.getElementsByClassName("ripsStdTxtBox") 'here we are opening dialog
msg_not.Click
Next msg_not


End If ' this End If of matchwww main statement
End Sub
```