# How to upload a file on prompt "Choose to upload the file" with VBA

Tags: javascript, excel, vba, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I have my below code which does the same thing which i want but it gets stuck at the code line after clicking the browse button `HTMLdoc.forms("upload").Item("fileobj").Click` it does not move further. Kindly advise ?

```
Private Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByRef lParam As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function FindWindowEx Lib "user32.dll" Alias "FindWindowExA" (ByVal hWnd1 As Long, ByVal hWnd2 As Long, ByVal lpsz1 As String, ByVal lpsz2 As String) As Long
Private Declare Function SendMessageByString Lib "user32.dll" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal wMsg As Long, ByVal wParam As Long, ByVal lParam As Any) As Long
Private Declare Function SetActiveWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function ShowWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal nCmdSHow As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function BringWindowToTop Lib "user32" (ByVal lngHWnd As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function EnableWindow Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal hWnd As Long, ByVal fEnable As Long) As Long
Private Declare Function GetActiveWindow Lib "user32" () As Long
Private Declare Function GetFocus Lib "user32.dll" () As Long
Private Declare Sub Sleep Lib "kernel32.dll" (ByVal dwMilliseconds As Long)
Private Const WM_CLOSE As Long = &H10
Private Const SW_SHOW As Integer = 5
Private Const WM_SETTEXT As Long = &HC
Private Const BM_CLICK As Long = &HF5&

Function Main(strCommandLine As String) 'is nessesary to execute on launch
    'Dim strCommandLine As String 'path passed from VBA
    'strCommandLine = "C:\Users\jk99991\Desktop\Automation\MVA\OutputFiles\BG\F3140.000" 'path passed from VBA
    'Sleep 25000 'wait to execute, can be smarter way to check if dialog is already open

    SaveAsWindow = FindWindow(vbNullString, "Choose file to Upload")

    If SaveAsWindow = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Couldn't find the SaveAsWindow" 'msg boxes are just for troubleshooting to see if right elements are found or not
    End If

    TextComboBox = FindWindowEx(SaveAsWindow, 0&, "ComboBoxEx32", vbNullString)
    If SaveAsWindow = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Couldn't find the SaveAsWindow"
        Stop
    End If

    ComboBox = FindWindowEx(TextComboBox, 0&, "ComboBox", vbNullString)
    If ComboBox = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Couldn't find the ComboBox"  
    End If

    EditComboBox = FindWindowEx(ComboBox, 0&, "Edit", vbNullString)
    If EditComboBox = 0 Then
        MsgBox "Couldn't find the EditComboBox"
    End If

    ''and wait/sleep
    Call SendMessageByString(EditComboBox, WM_SETTEXT, 0, strCommandLine) 'here goes variable from VBA "strCommandLine"
    DoEvents
    SaveButton = FindWindowEx(SaveAsWindow, 0&, "Button", "&Open")
    Call EnableWindow(SaveButton, True)
    Call SendMessage(SaveButton, BM_CLICK, 0&, ByVal 0&)

End Function
```

Below is the VBA code but it gets stuck after clicking the browse button. The script does not executes further till i manually cancel the window promt.

```
Set HTMLdoc = IE.Document

HTMLdoc.forms("upload").Item("fileobj").Click'Stops here does not move ahead 
Application.Wait (Now() + TimeValue("00:00:04"))

Call Main(nPath)  
Set HTMLAs = HTMLdoc.getElementsByTagName("strong")

For Each HTMLa In HTMLAs
    Debug.Print HTMLa.innerText
    If InStr(1, HTMLa.innerText, "Upload") <> 0 Then
        HTMLa.Click
    End If
Next HTMLa
```

Comment: Does stuck mean it errors on that line? What does the error say?

Comment: No it does not gives error. Stuck means does not move to the next code to the wait code. You can refer the link [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45377777/choose-file-to-upload-dialog-merge-vbs-and-vba-process/52076720#52076720] which landed me till here. i do not allowed to use vb6 in my organization.